# failed to run Angular application getting error : Schema validation failed

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular7

I am using Angular 7 for my Application and I am getting error while running it on development server .

I did **ng serve**

**but I got error below**

```
      D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1>ng lint -fix Your
     global Angular CLI version (7.3.9) is greater than your local version
     (7.1.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

     To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
     false".

 Schema validation failed with the following errors:  
 Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
     Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:   
Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
         at MergeMapSubscriber.project (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
         at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._next (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
         at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
         at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
        at InnerSubscriber._next (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
        at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
         at MapSubscriber._next (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
        at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
        at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\suman\ftoss\New TFS\FtossAngularWeb\Pre11WebV1\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
```

Details OF my Angular Application

**Angular.json - >**

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ftoss": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ftoss",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "src/fonts/styles.css",
              "src/fonts/stylesheet.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angularev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ftoss:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ftoss:buildroduction"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ftoss:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["/src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ftoss-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angularrotractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ftosserve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ftosserveroduction"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ftoss"
}
```

What I tried -  >

- I uninstalled npm from my project and again installed it , again I got same issue
- I did npm  cache clear again I got same issue
- List item

Comment: just had the same error with a new project... weird... I think that I messed something up with `npm audit fix --force`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I did some testing and on my side (check out my comment in the question) it seems that the `npm audit fix` breaks the dependencies and causes `ng serve` to yield on that error.
It seems to have to do with a dependency and I hope they'll fix it soon...

Answer (score 14):

This is due to `npm audit fix` installing a newer version of the [@angular-devkit/build-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions) package, specifically the 0.800.x versions, which **has breaking changes** from the 0.13.9 version. Thus, running the 0.800 version of this package breaks the angular-cli when used with Angular 7.

To fix this issue install the older stable package version with:

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.9`

Answer (score 2):

Even I ran into the same problem. As @Ardzii suggested the issue is with '`npm audit fix`' command. I cloned a new repo and installed the node packages again without running the npm audit command and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think its with the rxjs incompatibility. Try running this

`npm install rxjs-compat`