# "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting this error when i tried to use MatToolBar in my angular app. 
In browser I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` and also get warnings in the console:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js 146:151-159
"export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2324:206-214
"export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

How can I resolve this? On github it is a closed issue.

Comment: Please add a code snippet with the content of your package.json file.

Comment: What version of angular core are you using? [Is it 8 by any chance?](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30413)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Compilation Warnings with Angular Material Declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417164/angular-compilation-warnings-with-angular-material-declarations)

Comment: I've seen these kinds of errors when Ivy is enabled. If you have it on try turning it off.

Comment: I try make it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417164/angular-compilation-warnings-with-angular-material-declarations but i can't solved

Comment: This one was a toughy for me too. Was trying to use Angular 7 with firebase. I was getting those errors alike when using ng serve. I dough a bit more and it looked like my @angular/core version was wrong...so thats my thought on where the issue was. I just upgraded to angiular 9.0.0 and everything is working now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved it, I just updated the dependency of angular material to 7 and angular version to 7.3.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

So apparently after wasting 1 hour on the same issue, it seems your angular version and the material version should be same i.e if your angular CLI version is 7, you should use material version 7.

Just change the dependencies "@angular/material" and "@angular/cdk" version to "7.3.7" and change "@angular/animations" to "7.2.15"

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I did this but now get: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ScullyLibModule -> IdleMonitorService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ScullyLibModule -> IdleMonitorService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for IdleMonitorService!

Comment: @Evan, it looks like you forgot to import the `IdleMonitorService` in your provider settings in your `AppModule`

Comment: This helped me with ngx-filesaver

Comment: This has solved it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

The solution is to ensure all your packages are of the same versions.

Check Package.json file to find if the packages are on the same version.

Then in the command line use the command

```
ng update @angular/core
```

This should solve the problem

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the above command will also update other parts of Angular.

Comment: this is lightly considered advice

Comment: This command will also try to update the angular version, which might be not what everyone was looking for.

Comment: The above command will update to latest angular, if you wanna update to a specific version you can add version at the last for ex: ng update @angular/cli@9.0.0

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved it, we need to install proper npm plugin version corresponding to angular version.

For instance, if you are installing `ngx-toastr` then run; `npm i ngx-toastr@10.1.0` for angular `8.x`, `7.x`, `6.x`.

Check the support link for `ngx-toastr` version support for angular, which can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr).

Answer (score 1):

At first, I used below commands

```
npm install -S @angular/cdk @angular/animations
npm uninstall @angular/core
npm install -S @angular/core
```

Now, this solved this issue but then I faced this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879099/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-viewportscroller)

> NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller

Solved that error by using the below command

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Answer (score 1):

WARNING in

```
./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/fesm2015/ng-select-ng-select.js
```

2560:52-70
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

> Just removed the ɵɵ from ɵɵdefineInjectable in the 3 occurrences in
>   ./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/fesm2015/ng-select-ng-select.js

and it's working properly, thanks.

Comment: I don't think removing code in "node_modules" folder is a good answer....

Comment: wtf!! awesome Answer ! and stupid ! Working for me XDDDDDD

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved this issue with Angular primeng. Just make sure @angular/cdk version and primeng version are same.
It will work.

Also, make sure of there same versions as well.
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",

Answer (score 0):

I used @angular/core 7.x.x and I found a similar problem after I have installed **npm install ngx-toastr --save**. The ngx-toastr was version 11.x.x but the @angular/core was version 7.x.x

I have fixed it by updating the @angular/core and it updated to version 8.2.10

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in my App.component.ts test as I hadn't declared providers in the test for all my providers in the constructor. The issue landed me the "no tests founds" issue.