# NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm building a simple angular application, using Angular Material to desing the front-end.
The app just have 2 components rendered in the same page. When I serve the app, this is returned in the console:

NullInjectorError: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterScroller -> ViewportScroller]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterScroller -> ViewportScroller]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller!"

AppModule.ts

```
          import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

      import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
      import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
      import { Material } from './Material';
      import { DataFormComponent } from './data-form/data-form.component';
      import { TemplateFormComponent } from './template-form/template-form.component';
      import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


      @NgModule({
        declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          DataFormComponent,
          TemplateFormComponent,
        ],
        imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          AppRoutingModule,
          Material,
          FormsModule
        ],
        providers: [],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
      export class AppModule { }
```

appComponents.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Material.ts(module for all angular material components)

```
                import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
            import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
            import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
            import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
            import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
            import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
            import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
            import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

            @NgModule({
                imports:
                [
                    BrowserAnimationsModule,
                    MatTabsModule,
                    MatCardModule,
                    MatToolbarModule,
                    MatFormFieldModule,
                    MatInputModule,
                    MatButtonModule
                ],
                exports:
                [
                    BrowserAnimationsModule,
                    MatTabsModule,
                    MatCardModule,
                    MatToolbarModule,
                    MatFormFieldModule,
                    MatInputModule,
                    MatButtonModule
                ],
            })
            export class Material { }

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-root',
              templateUrl: './app.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
            })
            export class AppComponent {
              title = 'forms';
            }
```

AppRoutingModule.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CursoModule } from './curso/curso.module';

const routes: Routes = [
 { 
  path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'curso'
 },
 { 
  path: 'curso', loadChildren: './curso/curso.module#CursoModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

cursp-routing.module.ts:

```
import { CursosComponent } from './cursos.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CursoListaComponent } from './curso-lista/curso-lista.component';

    const routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: CursoListaComponent
    }
    ]


 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class CursoRouting { }
```

Comment: Update your question with AppRoutingModule

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had the same error - **updating Angular in a project workes for me** (it is a new project with only Angular Material, few simple components and simple routing).

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0

The error ocurred after I did:

```
npm install -S @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
npm uninstall @angular/core
npm install -S @angular/core
```

as a solution for error **"export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'** (thrown after adding Angular Material to a brand new project).

It worked until I added routing and got **NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller**. But as mentioned in the beginning - updating the whole project to Angular v8 seems the solution.

Comment: I had gone through the same process described in this answer but when I ran `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` I got the error `Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "8.2.0-next.2", would install "8.1.2")
                  Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "8.2.0-next.2" (extended), would install "8.1.2").` so I had to run `ng update @angular/compiler` first and then update the cli and core and everything worked!

Comment: It failed due to some issues, maybe due to permission issue and I had to bring things up again after deleting node_modules and doing npm install with administrative rights.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it was because I had `*cdkVirtualFor` on the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` element. Once I moved it into a child `ng-container` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all of your packages are the same version. See this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31425

Answer (score 1):

if you think that you are set all config in each ngmodule files and it's not working. you have a issue with the version of angular core, angular material and angular cdk. so do this:

solved by deleting node_modules/ and package-lock.json / and yarn-lock (if exist) and running a fresh npm install

Answer (score 0):

Remember to verify that other matMenu elements that **don't** use **cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport** use the regular *ngFor instead of ***cdkVirtualFor**.