# NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller!" angular 7

Tags: angular

ERROR NullInjectorError: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterScroller -> ViewportScroller]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterScroller -> ViewportScroller]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller!"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879099/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-viewportscroller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879099/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-viewportscroller)

Comment: No i get an error, i can't update

Answer (score 1):

Add your service in the providers of `app.module.ts` file