# Angular export not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, compiler-errors, package.json

Hello I have updated my angular dependencys. Now i get the following errors.

```
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/platform-browser.js 4409:15-24
"export 'ɵAPP_ROOT' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 3530:4-16
"export 'ɵLOCALE_DATA' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 3532:8-20
"export 'ɵLOCALE_DATA' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/platform-browser.js 4218:23-38
"export 'ɵ_sanitizeStyle' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 7351:12-27
"export 'ɵlooseIdentical' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 4381:8-23
"export 'ɵɵallocHostVars' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 4382:8-17
"export 'ɵɵstyling' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 6167:8-17
"export 'ɵɵstyling' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 4386:8-22
"export 'ɵɵstylingApply' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in D:/AffiliateShop/angular8-springboot-client/node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js 6171:8-22
"export 'ɵɵstylingApply' was not found in '@angular/core'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

This is my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-wiegmann",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.22",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^9.3.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.1",
    "ng-material-multilevel-menu": "^4.12.2",
    "ng-quill": "^4.5.3",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.20",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.6"
  }
}
```

What is the error that caused this problem. It happens after I made a npm update of all components. I dont know what is the cause of this problem.I am using Angular 10 now and cdk 9. Now my app is not starting anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433781/export-%c9%b5%c9%b5inject-was-not-found-in-angular-core)

Answer (score 1):

How did you update your dependencies ?

You'll need to do `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` to update all the Angular core dependencies.

Also, I guess you are seeing the issue because there's a major version mismatch between `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material`

To avoid such scenarios, always leverage the angular schematics and perform:: `ng update @angular/material`

`ng update @angular/material` will update both `cdk` and `material` ensuring compatibility.

Please follow the guidelines provided in [Angular update guidelines](https://update.angular.io/) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have upgraded your project to 10th version i.e., to say `"@angular/cli": "~10.0.1"`, correct?

Then you also have to run or install the following dependencies to ensure you have no errors and you can run `ng serve` command.

```bash
npm install @angular/core@10 @angular/material@10 @angular/cdk@10 @angular/common@10 @angular/forms@10 @angular/animations@10 @angular/platform-browser@10 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10 @angular/platform-server@10 typescript@3.7.7
```