# error in angular Material and app-root is empty

Tags: angular, web

hello everyone I'm a beginner in Angular and I used angular material component but nothing appear in browser and when I inspect I found app-root empty any solutions?

this is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
//import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is app.component.html:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<app-menu></app-menu>
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the terminal or in the console?

Comment: in the console I find only this warning : export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Comment: maybe the issue is somewhere else then? could you share more code? is the code by any chance in a repo?

Comment: I think you may have some dependency issues, if you want you can share your `package.json` file and I may try to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433781/export-%c9%b5%c9%b5inject-was-not-found-in-angular-core)

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz this is didn't help me

Comment: `
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",

`

Comment: ah ok :( , anyway copying your dependencies give me a different error, so I really am afraid that I would need more info  (at the very least the whole package.json file) before I can try to help :'(

Comment: okay this is the devdependencies part :

    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",