# ./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2020/router.mjs:2789:20-33 - Error: export 'ɵis

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-install

I have problem in npm install all package's is added but not working in
Error
./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2020/router.mjs:2789:20-33 - Error: export 'ɵisStandalone' (imported as 'ɵisStandalone') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Chang

{
"name": "cuba",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/animations": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
"@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
"@angular/compiler": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
"@angular/forms": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/google-maps": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/localize": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/service-worker": "~15.2.0",
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^15.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^4.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^35.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "^35.0.1",
"@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^7.0.0",
"@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "^15.0.1",
"@kolkov/angular-editor": "^2.1.0",
"@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^9.1.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^10.0.1",
"@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
"@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^6.0.2",
"@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^6.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
"@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^11.0.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.1.0",
"angular-archwizard": "^7.0.0",
"angular-calendar": "^0.30.1",
"angular-count-to": "0.0.3",
"angular-routing": "^0.3.1",
"angular2-knob": "^1.1.15",
"angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^5.0.4",
"angularx-flatpickr": "^7.0.0",
"animate.css": "^4.1.1",
"apexcharts": "^3.36.3",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
"bootstrap-scss": "^5.2.3",
"date-fns": "^2.29.3",
"feather-icons": "^4.29.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"leaflet": "^1.9.3",
"mousetrap": "^1.6.5",
"ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.4",
"ng-chartist": "^7.1.1",
"ng-gallery": "^7.1.2",
"ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
"ng2-datepicker": "^12.0.0",
"ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
"ng2-google-charts": "^7.0.0",
"ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
"ng5-slider": "^1.2.6",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^15.0.0",
"ngx-dropzone": "^3.1.0",
"ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^13.0.0",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.2",
"ngx-joyride": "^2.5.0",
"ngx-masonry": "^14.0.1",
"ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^15.0.0",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
"ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
"ngx-tabset": "^2.2.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^16.0.1",
"photoswipe": "^5.3.0",
"rxjs": "~7.5.6",
"sweetalert2": "^11.4.8",
"typescipt": "^1.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
"@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~15.2.0",
"@types/chartist": "^0.11.1",
"@types/feather-icons": "^4.7.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.7.11",
"@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.9",
"@types/node": "^18.7.9",
"codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
"jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"swiper": "^8.4.5",
"ts-node": "~10.9.1",
"tslib": "^2.4.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.8.4",
"webpack": "^5.75.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
}
}

Comment: i try  but not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433781/export-%C9%B5%C9%B5inject-was-not-found-in-angular-core

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` ? it looks like you have incompatible Angular versions